# Why is environ['QUERY_STRING'] returning a zero length string?

Tags: python, ajax, apache, client-server

I found the solution to my (dumb) problem and listed it below.

I'm using Python 2.7.1+ on Ubuntu 11.04. The client/server are on the same computer.

From the Wing debugger, I know the server code is being called and I can walk through the code one line at a time.  In this instance, I know 22 bytes were transferred.

In Firebug, I saw this data under the Net Post tab:

```
Parameter   application/x-www-form-urlencoded
fname   first
lname   last
Source
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 22 fname=first&lname=last
```

This is the client code that I'm using:

```
<html>
     <form action="addGraphNotes.wsgi" method="post">
         First name: <input type="text" name="fname" /><br />
         Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" /><br />
         <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</html>
```

And this is the server code:

```
import urlparse 

def application(environ, start_response):
    output = []

    # the environment variable CONTENT_LENGTH may be empty or missing
    try:
    # NOTE: THIS WORKS. I get a value > 0 and the size appears correct (22 bytes in this case)
        request_body_size = int(environ.get('CONTENT_LENGTH', 0))
    except (ValueError):
        request_body_size = 0

    try:
        # environ['QUERY_STRING'] returns ""
        **values = urlparse.parse_qs( environ['QUERY_STRING'] )**
    except:
        output = ["parse error"]
```

In the Wing debugger, I've verified that data is being passed from the client to the server:

```
>>> environ['wsgi.input'].read()
'fname=first&lname=last'
```

**FOUND MY PROBLEM. I COPIED AND PASTED IN THE WRONG CODE. THIS IS THE CODE I WAS USING FOR FORMS BUT STOP ADDING IT WHEN I STARTED USING AJAX AND STOPPED USING FORMS. Now, everything is working fine.**

```
# When the method is POST the query string will be sent
# in the HTTP request body which is passed by the WSGI server
# in the file like wsgi.input environment variable.
request_body = environ['wsgi.input'].read(request_body_size)

values = parse_qs(request_body)
```

Comment: Have you tried printing out the entire `environ` dict?

Comment: See edited question for additional details.

Answer (score 3):

You're doing a `POST` query so the `QUERY_STRING` is indeed going to be empty as it represents the query string of a `GET` request (it can also appear in other request types but it's unrelated to the problem at hand). You are supposed to parse `POST` data by consuming the `wsgi.input` stream.

Comment: I tried 'get' but that didn't change anything.  All my other form/submit code that I wrote earlier used 'post' and the code worked fine.  Something seems to be 'broken' on this machine and I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: I've been using post in my form submits all along and everything worked just fine. Until I starting using this computer.